# Python & Beautifulsoup 4 - findAll is not getting all elements, only gets the first?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape shoe sizes from KicksUSA.com and I seem to be unable to get the shoe sizes that are displayed on product pages. Taking this page as an example - https://www.kicksusa.com/jordan/air-jordan-13-retro-atmosphere-greyblack-white-univ-red-414571-016.html - I am trying to get all the sizes displayed there.

The sizes appear in 3 locations that I've noticed -

1. As `data-label` attributes of `a` elements within the `div.input-box.validation-passed` element (or, if we go one element above, within the `dd.last` element)
2. As `option` elements with `price` equal to `0` within the `select` element
3. Within `spConfig` JS code

Any attempt to get data from the first location (`data-label` attributes of `a` elements) resulted in `None`.

When I used the following code:

```
size = soup2.find('dd', attrs={'class': 'last'})
getsize = size.find('select')
getgetsize = str([e.get_text() for e in getsize.findAll('option', attrs={'price': '0'})])
```

I get nothing, as if the `option` elements with that attribute didn't exist.

When I run this code:

```
size = soup2.find('dd', attrs={'class': 'last'})
getsize = size.find('select')
getgetsize = str([e.get_text() for e in getsize.findAll('option')])
```

I get only the first result, which is `Choose an Option...`

Does anyone have an idea how to get the data I'm after? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is the snippet that bypasses the protection:

```
        headers = {
            'Host': 'www.kicksusa.com',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                          'Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36',
            'DNT': '1',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7',
            'Cookie': 'visid_incap_459049=Evije6RoRAG1GuxEpbckJA4Ch1wAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABk8hUjgpv63FQ2WQOlcukw; incap_ses_1079_459049=UXVgNfGObEuAWEiyCWH5DiGJm1wAAAAA4XovM6FTnjT4ZWyukyoWxw==',
        }
        data2 = requests.get(url3, headers=headers)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(data2.text, 'html.parser')
```

You have to edit the `visid_incap_...=...` and `incap_ses_...=...` values by opening kicksusa.com and going to Cookies->kicksusa.com

Comment: `getsize = size.find('select')` I don't see any select tag, are you trying to find the right tag?

Comment: looks like the page is protected against automative processes, including simulation of a browser such as Selenium. If I look at what it returns when I use request, I get the message of it doing `Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID:`, and with Selenium, the same

Comment: @bhansa - On the product page, right click on one of the sizes and then Inspect, after the list of `a` elements there is the `select` tag

Comment: @chitown88 - Sorry, it's my fault for not including the snippet that bypasses it - original post edited to include it.

Comment: ah ok. Thanks. I'll try again

Answer (score 0):

With findAll() you get several groups, and you need to access them by e.group(0):

```
size = soup2.find('dd', attrs={'class': 'last'})
getsize = size.find('select')
for e in getsize.findAll('option')]):
      l = len(e)
      for i in l:
            getgetsize[i] = str(e.group(i).get_text())
```

Comment: When I use this code, I get `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. I removed a parenthesis and a bracket from this line `for e in getsize.findAll('option')]):` so it looks like this because I was getting an error `for e in getsize.findAll('option'):`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to take blood from a stone all along. The data I was looking for is simply not there - the website does some JS DOM manipulation. The only way to do this (as far as I know) is to get the `spConfig` JS code and use regex to get the data from there. I'm off to fiddle with regex now, thanks everyone for ideas and assistance!